# Strange behavior of ASP .net TextBox

Tags: asp.net, webforms, textbox

I have a simple ASP net web form that consists of two textboxes one single line and one multiline in addition to a fileupload control and a button.

the page works perfect and the button triggers the post back as usual. But when I copy and paste text from "Web pages" in particular and paste them in the multiline textbox the post back is never triggered, sometimes I get time out error, sometimes I get bad request!!!

This behavior is generated only in IIS, it is not observed in IIS express.

The text is not that long, it is about 30 lines or less, but I noticed that when deleting some lines of text the issue is resolved and no errors is generated, but I can't find anything special in those lines that are deleted, no control characters or any other special characters.

Any idea? has someone encounter this same situation?

Comment: did you set any `Model Validation` to the `Multiline TextBox` like maxlength

Comment: show your code because your question is half baked

Comment: Copying from web page is likely carrying over some HTML, which may be posted to the server and intercepted as a bad request. [Try disabling ValidateRequest](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation) for the page as a quick test. `<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false"%> `

Comment: You should create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can localize where the issue is.

Comment: It is very disappointing that some people are down voting my question, I really suffer from this problem, this is really impolite, i may remove the question and never use stack overflow again

Comment: But you haven't asked a good question. You've stated a problem, but we have no idea what you could be doing to cause the issue. It's far too open ended without seeing the specific code involved. If you follow my advice and create an MCVE, that would improve the question immensely.

Answer (score 0):

That is strange problem, never had experienced it but i think it can be a problem related to browser cache or browser compatibility issue. Make sure you have declared right version of browser in your HTML code. Also, try to debug the problem by placing the breakpoint and see it runs every time or not.

Comment: I have tried several browsers on several platforms with same problem, no break point is triggered

Comment: This is not a good answer. You should gather more details before attempting to answer. Don't just say "try this". See [Can we care a little more about quality instead of quantity, please?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316112/can-we-care-a-little-more-about-quality-instead-of-quantity-please)